# Can Sack suffocate someone by covering them?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In the Marvel Comics, one of the Gene Nation members is simply known as Sack, a mutant who can cover an opponent with his transparent, gel-like body and make them fight for him, due to his body being very weak. I am curious: has he ever used this ability to try and suffocate someone? After all, if their face is covered in a thick, gel-substance, I imagine it would be very hard to breathe.

Answer (score 1):

The very short answer to this one is no. [Sack's mutation](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Sack_(Earth-616)) isn't that he's strictly a *liquid*, but rather that he can turn into a sort of ethereal energy and merge with another being, allowing him to operate their body like a meat-puppet.

That being said, the process of absorption **is 100% fatal** to anyone who doesn't have a mutant healing factor.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Uncanny X-Men #324**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_324)</sup></sub>